# How to preserve NAs when using format in R?

Tags: r, format

I have a matrix with some `NA` that I'd like to format and then write to a CSV file, replacing each `NA` with two dashes. However, all of the `NA` get converted to characters by `format`, and `write.csv` then fails to detect and replace them.

After reading through the help file for `format`, setting  `na.encode=FALSE` seemed like the logical thing to do, but that didn't fix the problem. I've also searched with Google and on this site for other people having this problem, but couldn't find any. This seems like it should have a simple answer, and has me beating my head against the wall.

A minimal example of my code looks like this:

```
data = matrix(c(pi, NA, pi*100, NA), 2, 2)
data.f = format(data, digits=4, nsmall=2)
write.csv(data.f, file="data.csv", na="--")
```

I'm using R 2.15.1. What is the correct way to do this?

*Edit: Can anyone explain why this even requires a workaround?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a more orthodox way to do this, but perhaps you can use `!is.na()` at the `format()` stage to prevent the `NA` values from being converted to characters.

Here's a minimal example along with the resulting CSV.

```
set.seed(1)
data <- matrix(rnorm(20), ncol=5)
data[sample(length(data), 5)] <- NA
data.f <- data
data.f[!is.na(data.f)] <- format(data.f[!is.na(data.f)], digits = 4, nsmall = 2)
write.csv(data.f, file = "data.csv", na = "--")
dput(write.csv(data.f, na = "--"))
# "","V1","V2","V3","V4","V5"
# "1","-0.62645"," 0.32951",--,--,--
# "2"," 0.18364","-0.82047",--,"-2.21470"," 0.94384"
# "3","-0.83563"," 0.48743"," 1.51178",--," 0.82122"
# "4"," 1.59528"," 0.73832"," 0.38984","-0.04493"," 0.59390"
# NULL
```

Comment: This works, thanks. I'm going to leave the question unanswered for a day or two to see if anyone can explain why this even requires a workaround, but if there's no posts after that I'll go ahead and accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible workaround

```
data = matrix(c(pi, NA, pi*100, NA), 2, 2)
data.f = format(data, digits=4, nsmall=2)
data.f <- replace(data.f, which(data.f == "     NA"), "--")
write.csv(data.f, file="data.csv")
```

Comment: Yes, I did consider something like this, but it seemed strange to me that something so simple would require a workaround at all.

Comment: Yeah - I kind of agree. On the other hand, when you think about what `format` is doing, the `data.f` object is just text which is nice for printing - therefore the information regarding `NA` is lost and simply coded as text.